# ImportError: cannot import name cross_validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I cannot import the cross_validation from sklearn library; I use sklearn version 0.20.0

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
```

later in the code:

```
features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(word_data, authors, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\me\M.Sc\Udacity_ML_course\ud120-projects-  master\naive_bayes\nb_author_id.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email_preprocess import preprocess
  File "../tools/email_preprocess.py", line 8, in <module>
    from sklearn import cross_validation
ImportError: cannot import name cross_validation
```

Comment: Post the code you're trying please, and the full traceback of the error

Comment: Are you thinking of [`cross_val_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This happens because there is no `cross_validation` object in `sklearn`. You're likely looking for something more like the `cross_validate` function. You can access that through

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
```

However, you don't need to import any cross-validation software to perform the train-test split, since that will just randomly sample from the data. Try

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

followed by

```
features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(word_data, authors, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
```

Answer (score 8):

`cross_validation` used to exist as a Scikit package*, but was deprecated at some point.

If you're looking for `train_test_split` as your code indicates, it's in `model_selection`:

```
from sklearn import model_selection

features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = model_selection.train_test_split(
    word_data, authors, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
```

<sub>*Looks like this changed in [0.18](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.18.html#model-selection-enhancements-and-api-changes).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using some files from a Udacity course, which used an **older version of sklearn.** Instead of spending unnecessary time reformatting code usage to meet the latest versions of all their dependencies, it was easier to install the old version.

This was possible because they provide a requirements.txt file.

`python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was also trying to install an old version of sklearn which is required for mini projects for ['Intro to Machine Learning'](https://github.com/udacity/ud120-projects) Udacity course.

I use Miniconda 3 with Python 2 environment on Windows 10.

Unfortunately, @Ben B's method with `pip` didn't work for me. I had errors which look like errors in the [scipy github issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5995):

```
Installing collected packages: scipy   Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\program files\python\2.x\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\reacodes\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-jzv_lz\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\reacodes\appdata\local\temp\pip-mqeonc-record\install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\program files\\python\\2.x\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\program files\\python\\2.x\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\program files\\python\\2.x\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\program files\\python\\2.x\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    ...
```

So I tried another method with `conda` described in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59986431/9930478):

```
conda install -c free scikit-learn=0.18.0
```