# Python error: cannot import name cross_validation

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, data-science

I tried to import cross_validation by using the following statement in python 2

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
```

but I am receiving the following error

> cannot import name cross_validation

Comment: You might want: 
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

Comment: Duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name cross_validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011739/importerror-cannot-import-name-cross-validation).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name cross\_validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011739/importerror-cannot-import-name-cross-validation)

Comment: @GotCubes Could you please explain how we use cross_validate for the below statement

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.test_train_split(X_new, 
    y, test_size = 0.2)

Answer (score 3):

`cross_validation` was removed in SKlearn 0.20. You can now import it as,

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
```

Basically all the cross validation related functions are moved under model_selection in SKlearn.

EDIT :

To import train_test_split,

`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

Comment: How do we modify the below statement:
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.test_train_split(X_new, y, test_size = 0.2)