# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation' ?? How to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm trying to import `train_test_split()` from `sklearn.cross_validation` but there is an error like 'No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'' this but I've already installed scikit-learn in anaconda.  So how to solve this can't understand.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-d05cc6ee7707> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'
```

Comment: Do `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name cross\_validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011739/importerror-cannot-import-name-cross-validation)

Comment: Please use a search engine to look for the answer first, then try Stack Overflow's search if that doesn't turn up the answer. This particular question has been asked and answered numerous times.

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

instead of

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

This is because the `sklearn.cross_validation` is now deprecated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use the below. from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split is depricated

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Answer (score -1):

So, instead of using `sklearn.cross_validation` you have to use

`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`

This is because the `sklearn.cross_validation` is now deprecated.