# Installing an old version of scikit-learn

Tags: python, windows, scikit-learn, pip, conda

**Problem Statment**

I'm trying to run some old python code that requires `scikit-learn 18.0` but the current version I have installed is `0.22` and so I'm getting a warning/invalid data when I run the code.

---

**What I've Tried**

I tried installing the specific version both in the terminal: `python -m pip install scikit-learn==0.18` and in `conda` and none of that has worked. All I can install is `v 0.22`. Help? Thanks.

---

**Error In Terminal**

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
>   Running setup.py clean for scikit-learn
>   Failed to build scikit-learn
>   Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
>   Found existing installation: scikit-learn 0.22.1
>   Uninstalling scikit-learn-0.22.1:
>   Successfully uninstalled scikit-learn-0.22.1
>   Running setup.py install for scikit-learn ... error
>   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Error through conda environment:

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
>   current channels:
>   - scikit-learn==0.18   this was after creating and activating the new environment

Comment: The following details need to be added to the question to adequately answer it: Python version, Conda version, and OS.

Comment: Please also post the full error message that occurs when you install scikit-learn through `pip`

Comment: In my case, I was able to "hack" the modern scikit learn to load a pickle created with a much older version: `sys.modules['sklearn.preprocessing.label'] = sys.modules['sklearn.preprocessing._label']`  This worked to load (and train from) a pickle created in scikit-learn version 0.21.X or earlier into a running scikitlearn version 1.3.0 (and from and Python 3.5 to Python 3.10).  Installing the old scikit learn with Python 3.10 appeared impossible in my pip case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tackling your issues one at a time:

> `python -m pip install scikit-learn==0.18` fails

This is probably due to the fact that `scikit-learn==0.18`, if you [check on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/0.18/#files) only has `whl` files for python 3.5 and 2.7 for windows, therefore `pip` downloads the source distribution and then fails in compiling it, probably because it doesn't work with newer python versions

> The following packages are not available from current channels

This happens, because `scikit-learn==18.0` simply does not exist in the default `conda` channels. On my win64 machine, the oldesst version that I can install is `19.0` (You can check by typing `conda search scikit-learn` in the `cmd`), so unfortunately no way to install using the default `conda` channels. There is a channel called `free` (found through the [anaconda website](https://anaconda.org/search?q=scikit-learn)) that has scikit-learn 18.0, so you could install with:

```
conda install -c free scikit-learn
```

To also make sure that the python version is compatible, I would just create a fitting environment:

```
conda create -n py35 -c free scikit-learn=0.18.0
```

Comment: Oh cool! I didn't know you could use `-c free` instead of `restore_free_channel` config option. That makes it sooo much easier. Now I have to change a bunch of my answers.

Comment: Hmm, I now notice that using the `anaconda` channel also seems to work, e.g., `conda search anaconda/win-64::scikit-learn=0.18`. This isn't the case for `defaults`, e.g., `conda search defaults/win-64::scikit-learn=0.18`.

Comment: This worked perfectly! thank you! i'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1):

I have a guess about what it's happening and I think you will find you answear here:

First let's check the python version installed within your system:

```sh
python --version                                                                                                                                                                              

> Python 3.8.0
```

If you're ready set and updated this should be your current python version, and I guess here lies the problem. You can check sickit-learn versions from its official pypi distribution page [here](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/#history). If you check the docs you will see that the package was meant to 2.7 or 3.5 python distributions.

So to run your code I guess the best way would be to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) or [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (my personal choice) where you can create a clean env for your tests.

```sh
# On your terminal
# First let's check if python2 is installed

python2 --version                                                                                                                                                                             > Python 2.7.17

# and pip

python2 -m pip --version                                                                                                                                                                      
> pip 19.3 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

# Now create a virtual env using virtualenvwrapper and python2 as our main python

mkdir py2
mkvirtualenv -p python2 -a py2  py2 

# After that the python command will be binded to your python2 installation
python --version
> Python 2.7.17

# Now lets install sckit lib
python -m pip install scikit-learn==0.18

python -m pip freeze                                                                                                                                                                      
> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
> scikit-learn==0.18
```

If everything is ok now you can run your code with no problems!

**Remember!!!!** Python 2 is [deprecated](https://pythonclock.org/) and you should update your code to use a more recent python distribution.

Also, virtualenv is a good practice when working with python, if you don't know it take your time to set up!

Comment: OP already shows Conda is present. Mixing Conda and Pip is not recommended, especially when the packages are available on Anaconda Cloud.  Adding in another virtual environment management tool is also not recommended.

Comment: His requirement referred to scikit-learn. He also mentioned using conda and pip as the install method. Of course, if you are using conda you don't need to use a virtualenv but that was not what I suggested.