# Why can't I import some of the modules in scikit-learn? (PyCharm)

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, importerror, install.packages

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import cross_validation
```

ExtraTreesClassifiers runs, and so does SelectFrom Model. But the latter two lines do not run. I get an error that says "ImportError: cannot import name 'cross_validation' from 'sklearn'."

I've checked in PyCharm to see if my interpreter has scikit-learn installed, and it's installed. I've uninstalled and reinstalled it from my terminal using pip3. I've tried running the file from my terminal, and it says "No such file or directory." I'm not sure what else to try.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I could do next?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Instead you should do `from sklearn.model_selection import KFold` for doing cross validation

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the line of code grays out when I try to use Kfold as a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

`cross_validation` was *used* to exist as a scipy package but is now deprecated and so it isn't advisable to use it.

You can use `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` instead
:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

You can also try downgrading it by installing an older version of sklearn to continue using the `cross_validation` package.

**References:**  [ImportError: cannot import name cross_validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011739/importerror-cannot-import-name-cross-validation)